# Contablizar número de ocorrências em um arquivo de log

Tags: python, txt, count

Estou tentando contar o número de ocorrências de múltiplos padrões de texto em um arquivo de log.

Meu código está contabilizando todas as linhas do arquivo para todos os padrões de texto.

Onde estou errando?

O arquivo de log se parece com isso:

> Feb  1 00:00:02 bridge kernel: INBOUND TCP: IN=br0 PHYSIN=eth0 OUT=br0 >PHYSOUT=eth1 SRC=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX DST=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX LEN=40 TOS=0x00 >PREC=0x00 TTL=110 ID=12973 PROTO=TCP SPT=220 DPT=6129 WINDOW=16384 RES=0x00 >SYN URGP=0
>   Feb  1 00:00:02 bridge kernel: INBOUND TCP: IN=br0 PHYSIN=eth0 OUT=br0 >PHYSOUT=eth1 SRC=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX DST=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX LEN=40 TOS=0x00 >PREC=0x00 TTL=113 ID=27095 PROTO=TCP SPT=220 DPT=6129 WINDOW=16384 RES=0x00 >SYN URGP=0

Meu código no momento está assim:

```
#!//usr/bin/python3

import sys
import os
import re

tipos= set()
cnt=0
p= re.compile ('bridge kernel:.*:')
with open (sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        match = p.search(line)
        if match:
            taux=(line.split(":") [3])
            tipos.add(taux)
        if taux in tipos:
            cnt+=1
        elif taux not in tipos:
            cnt=0
        d=dict.fromkeys(tipos,contador)
print (d)
```

Comment: Traduzi o pergunta. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

na linha 18 Substitua "contador" por "cnt"

Comment: Feito. Foi apenas um erro de digitação. Obrigado.

Comment: show, fico feliz em ajudar. ;)